# Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 0 when i am using Google Map jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, geofencing

I am working on Geo Fencing So I am using Google Dependencies ["android-maps-utils"](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.maps.android/android-maps-utils/0.4) 
and ["geopackage-android-map"](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mil.nga.geopackage.map/geopackage-android-map/1.3.1)

I installed these jar in my system and using them in pom.xml file

its working fine in eclipse IDE but when i built the project and run project jar separately, that time it's throwing Expecetion given below :

Thanks in advance for helping.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 0
        at java.time.temporal.ValueRange.checkValidValue(Unknown Source)
        at java.time.temporal.ChronoField.checkValidValue(Unknown Source)
        at java.time.LocalDate.of(Unknown Source)
        at java.time.LocalDateTime.of(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryFileHeader.decodeMsDosFormatDateTime(CentralDirectoryFileHeader.java:127)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryFileHeader.getTime(CentralDirectoryFileHeader.java:116)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarEntry.<init>(JarEntry.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries.getEntry(JarFileEntries.java:316)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries.access$400(JarFileEntries.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries$EntryIterator.next(JarFileEntries.java:366)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries$EntryIterator.next(JarFileEntries.java:350)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile$2.nextElement(JarFile.java:204)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile$2.nextElement(JarFile.java:195)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive$EntryIterator.next(JarFileArchive.java:189)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive$EntryIterator.next(JarFileArchive.java:174)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:85)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
```

Comment: the error is pretty self explanatory: the valid values are within the range 1-12, and you pass 0.

Comment: we can't change google map jar and i am not passing month year any where this exception is coming when i am running the jar.

Comment: that is still what is happening. you'll need to figure out where it is called, and change the code if need be.

Comment: this is not code issue this exception is occurring only when i am using google map jar in my project. And we can't make change in that google map jar

Comment: yes. and the issue is that a 0 is passed where that is not a valid value. Not much more we can say about that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was fixed in spring-boot 2.1.12
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/19595

Answer (score 0):

For those who use Java `Month.of(0)` method to get a `Month` value from int.

You should add `1` to month value (`January` is 1).

```
public static Month of(int month) {
    if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
        throw new DateTimeException("Invalid value for MonthOfYear: " + month);
    }
    return ENUMS[month - 1];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This Api takes mont number in format 1-12. You need add one `+1` when you are going from place that uses 0-11 for counting months.